# Numerical solver for maxwell equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, physics

Just curious if someone has come across a package where I can simply solve the basic maxwell equations(just the curl equations). I'm just interested in solving it on a 2-d plate out of interest. Anyone come across such a package in their travels?

Thanks

Comment: Software package I mean, such as written in Matlab, etc. Sorry about not being clear.

Comment: I don't know what you're familiarity with python is, but it really wouldn't be *all* that horrible to code you're own numerical solver for Maxwell's equations if you use the [Finite Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method)

Answer (score 1):

You mean "numerically solve", right? In this case I would suggest you to give [FiPy](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/) an earnest shot. It's reasonably simple and fairly well documented. It may be the answer to your problem.

PS: FiPy is based on the Finite Volume Method (FVM).